# how to overlay an image over an image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, overlay

I'm trying to figure out how to overlay an image or textbox over an image in WPF. The base image will be hosting a video feed from a Kinect sensor and I want to overlay an image on it. For example the video feed will have a textbox on the feed that will update a counter or an image of a tree on top of the video feed.

Is there a straightforward way of achieving this in the layout? Is it just a matter of changing properties or adding a canvas?

The below picture better illustrates what it is I'm trying to do:

[image: Controls over a live video feed]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use two transparent canvas inside the Grid without any row and column then place your objects in Back and front Canvas accordingly they will overlap

that is:

```
<Grid>
    <VideoControl><!-- I've never tried video --></VideoControl>
    <TextBlock Text="My Text" />
</Grid>
```

Usually you specify `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` and `<Grid.RowDefinitions>` but since you do not du that here the controls will overlap

HTH

Answer (score 6):

The usual way for me to overlay items in WPF is just to put all of the elements in a `Grid`. If you do not define any Columns or Rows the elements will overlap.

**Example**

```
<Grid>
  <Image Source="image on lowest layer" />
  <Image Source="overlaying image" />
</Grid>
```